# How i can show the href of all my <a> links inside a span beisde the <a>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following markup, which represents a table which have `<a>` inside its `<td>`:-

[image]

now i am trying to find a way using javascript, to show the href of all the `<a class="ms-listlink">` beside them.so the `<td`> will contain something as follow:-

```
Design Transfer
http://***/buisnessfunctions/pmo/progammes/136/
```

instead of just showing the text:-

```
Design Transfer
```

so is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5):

You can do this without javascript - css has a `content` property that can access attributes. Here's an example:

```css
a {
  display: block;
}

a:after {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 1em;
  content: attr(href);
}
```

```html
<a href="http://google.com">Google</a>
<a href="http://zombo.com">Zombocom</a>
```

Comment: Clever solution -- `attr` is underused IMHO

Answer (score 1):

Loop through each link, read its href property and insertAfter the link.

```
$('.ms-listlink').each(function(){
   var link = $(this).attr('href');
   $(this).insertAfter('<span>'+ link +'</span>');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the CSS solution above, but here's the JS solution FWIW

```
$('.ms-listlink').each(function() {
  const href = $(this).attr('href');
  const $td = $(this).closest('td');
  $($td).append(href);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I really like the CSS answer.  Tiny, easy, concise.  Just in case you are curious (or for some reason require a JS-only solution), here is a way to do it in plain vanilla JavaScript (no additional libraries):

```
<div id=container>
  <a href=https://google.com    >GOOGLE   </a> <span></span> <br />
  <a href=https://faceboook.com >FACEBOOK </a> <span></span> <br />
  <a href=https://yahoo.com     >YAHOO    </a> <span></span> <br />
</div>

<script>
var container = document.getElementById('container');

var anchor = container.getElementsByTagName('a');
var span   = container.getElementsByTagName('span');

for(var item in anchor) {
    span[item].innerHTML = anchor[item].href;
}

</script>
```

*NOTE: If you need the url's to be a clickable part of the hyperlinks, put the span's *inside* the 'a' tags.